# defering javascript with jquery issues and versioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, versioning

I'm having some issues with defering javascript. From [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#DeferLoadingJS) about defering js, I've found the following code, edited to my needs:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    var element2 = document.createElement("script");
    element2.src = "jquery.validate.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("script");
    element3.src = "fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.2.1.4.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element3);
 }

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

This code adds the 3 .js files to the page, and they show up in the inspector. Now the issue is that I have more code on my page, using jquery & the google analytics

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
   //some code
});
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '*********']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Now I have put all my code into the `//some code` section, so code for initializing the fancybox and adding event listeners. Now an issue I'm getting is when refreshing, sometimes I get **`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`**. I can only assume this is because the **other files are loaded before the jQuery file**. How should I solve this?

Also, does code inside the `main.js` (the .js file with all the other js code required on the page) still need to be in the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` or not?
I used to put a lot of javascript in between my code in php so it wouldn't need to be sent to the page if it isn't needed, but I guess using an external .js file could benefit due to being cachable.

And on a sidenote: apparantly using `bar.js?v=1.0` for **versioning** is BAD (according to El Goog, because then some proxy's don't cache it), so the best method is to always change the file name, like so: `bar.1.0.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not loaded when you call "$(document).ready(function(){", because it is not yet included in the page, but loaded after the page loads.

This can be solved by executing all your code after the jquery file is done loading:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var element = document.createElement("script");
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    element.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    var element2 = document.createElement("script");
    element2.src = "jquery.validate.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("script");
    element3.src = "fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.2.1.4.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element3);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Quick and dirty implementation, you should check for all the included files to be done loading, and create some sort of object that triggers an event that is called when alle the files are loaded
element.onload = function {
  $(document).ready(function() { ... });
}
</script>
```

[Edit]:  jQuery depended files are loaded before jQuery: You have to apply the same method and create the script objects of the other files after the jQuery script onload event fires. You indeed should not have to use $(document).ready() anymore, because the files are included at onload which is always after domready.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.onload = function() {
      /jQuery is ready, now load the files that build on the jQuery framework
      var element2 = document.createElement("script");
      element2.src = "jquery.validate.js";
      document.body.appendChild(element2);
      var element3 = document.createElement("script");
      element3.src = "fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.2.1.4.js";
      document.body.appendChild(element3);
   }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Comment: I see what you mean but all my code is currently inside an external .js file and I can't pass the element var to that. The question is that I need to load in all the other files AFTER JQuery, and it would be best that I wouldn't need to edit all external files for this because these can be updated often.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I've edited my answer.